# TypeError: invalid file: When trying to make a file name a variable

Tags: file, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to represent a file location as a variable because the finial script will be run on another machine. This is the code I have tried followed by the error I get. It seems to me that some how python is adding "\" and that is causing the problem. If that is the case how do I get it not to insert the "\"? Thank you

```
F = 'C:\Documents and Settings\myfile.txt','r'
f = open(F)
```

and the error

```
TypeError: invalid file: ('C:\\Documents and Settings\\myfile.txt', 'r')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
f=open('C:\Documents and Settings\myfile.txt','r')
```

Instead of using the variable F. the way you have it `'r'` is part of the file name, which it is not.

Comment: Removing the 'r' fixed it than you!

Answer (score 5):

From the docs:

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Try this:

```
F = r'C:\Documents and Settings\myfile.txt'
f = open(F, 'r')
```

About the "double backslashes" - you need to escape backslashes in your strings or use `r'string'`, see this:

- http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html

E.g. try this:

```
>>> a = 'a\nb'
>>> print a
a
b
```

To get what you expect, you need this:

```
>>> a = r'a\nb'
>>> print a
a\nb
```

or this:

```
>>> a = 'a\\nb'
>>> print a
a\nb
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `/` or `\`, you should do this:

```
import os
F = os.path.join(
    "C:",
    os.path.join(
        "Documents and Settings", "myfile.txt"
    )
)
f = open(F, 'r')`
```

so that it uses `/` or `\` according to your os.

(Although if you write `C:/` it must mean you want to run your code on Windows... Hum...)